# Selecting top most row in Bigquery based on conditions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a huge table, where sometimes 1 product ID has multiple specifications. I want to select the newest but unfortunately, I don't have the date information. please consider this example dataset

```
Row ID  Type    Sn      Sn_Ind  
1   3   SLN     SL20    20      
2   1   SL      SL      0   
3   2   SL      SL      0   
4   1   M       SL21    10
5   3   M       SL21    10      
6   1   SLN     SL20    20
```

I used the below query to somehow group the products in give them row numbers like

```
with cleanedMasterData as(
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Sn DESC, Sn_Ind DESC) AS rn
   FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
-- where rn = 1
)
select * from cleanedMasterData
```

Please find below the example table after cleaning

```
Row ID  Type    Sn      Sn_Ind  rn  
1   1   SL      SL      0       1
2   1   M       SL21    10      2
3   1   SLN     SL20    20      3

4   2   SL      SL      0       1

5   3   M       SL21    10      1
6   3   SLN     SL20    20      2
```

but if you see for ID 2 and 3, I can easily select the top row with  `where rn = 1`
but for ID 1, my preferred row would be 2 because that is the newest.

My question here is how do I prioritise a value in column so that I can get the desired solution like :

```
Row ID  Type    Sn      Sn_Ind  rn  

1   1   M       SL21    10      1
2   2   SL      SL      0       1
3   3   M       SL21    10      1
```

As the values are fixed in `Sn` column - for ex `SL, SL20, SL19, SL21` etc - If somehow I can give weightage to these values and create a new temp column with weightage and sort based on it, then?

Thank you for your support in advance!!

Comment: Sorting by the `SN` column is problematical, because it is text, yet you want the trailing number to be part of the sort as a digit.

Comment: yes, unfortunately, there is no other column I can use for sorting, but as the values are fixed - for ex ```SL, SL20, SL19, SL21``` etc - If somehow I can give weightage to these values and create a new temp column with weightage and sort based on it, then?

Comment: mysql and google-bigquery are two different products with different syntaxes and functionality.

Comment: You either need to use a massive case statement or have a third table that contains the order of these items or if SN can be sorted using the digit in the field values, then you can convert the digits to number and sort that way. Your examples are inconsistent, so I don't really know what logic you should be using.

Comment: not really, I just needed 1 case statement. you can have a look at my own answer below! Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below

```
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE TRUE
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY IF(Sn = 'SL', 0, 1) DESC, Sn DESC) = 1
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't difficult, I tried a few things and it worked out. If anyone can optimize the below solution even more that would be awesome.

first the dataset

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
SELECT 1 ID, 'SLN' Type, 'SL20' Sn, 20 Sn_Ind UNION ALL
  SELECT 1  , 'SL'     ,   'SL'    ,     0     UNION ALL
  SELECT 2  , 'SL'     ,   'SL'    ,     0     UNION ALL
  SELECT 1  , 'M'      ,   'SL21'  ,    10     UNION ALL
  SELECT 3  , 'M'      ,   'SL21'  ,    10     UNION ALL
  SELECT 1  , 'SLN'    ,   'SL20'  ,    20   
)
```

```
with weightage as(
SELECT
  *,
  MAX(CASE Sn WHEN 'SL' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Sn) AS weightt,
FROM
  `project.dataset.table`
ORDER BY
  weightt DESC, Sn DESC
), main as (
select * EXCEPT(rn, weightt)
from (
    select * ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY weightt DESC, Sn DESC) AS rn
from weightage )
where rn = 1
)
select * from main
```

after this, I can get the desired result

```
Row ID  Type    Sn      Sn_Ind 

1   1   M       SL21    10      
2   2   SL      SL      0       
3   3   M       SL21    10
```